# Error sending bitmap between activities android

Tags: android, android-activity, bitmap

I already know how to send images between activities.
 As I can't emulate the android app in Eclipse, every time I want to test it I have to install it into my phone, so I can't see the error it returns me.

As I said before, I am having problems between 2 activities when I want to send and Image from "Acceso_Camara" (main Activity) to "Visualizar_Imagen" (activity in which I want to recieve the image). 
Here, you are the code I did to send the image:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Intent siguienteActividad = new Intent(this,Visualizar_Imagen.class);
    switch(requestCode) {
    case REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE:
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("Imagen");
            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, bs);
            siguienteActividad.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
            startActivity(siguienteActividad);
        }
    break;
    case SELECT_PICTURE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, bs);
            siguienteActividad.putExtra("byteArray", bs.toByteArray());
            startActivity(siguienteActividad);
        }
    break;
    }
}
```

"REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE" and "SELECT_PICTURE" are setted as "private static final int" and each one as a value. 
Recieving activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visualizar__imagen);
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("byteArray")) {
        imageView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray"), 0,
                getIntent().getByteArrayExtra("byteArray").length);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

And when I run the app, it gives me an error, saying "App has stopped"

Any ideas?

P.S: I have also tried not to compress the image to send, and I actually have no error, but anthing is given on the "Visualizar_Imagen" activity.

---

Okey, so this is the given error, it seems it has no data to send to the next activity. Any ideas?

```
04-27 18:02:20.730: E/AndroidRuntime(11283): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { act=inline-data (has extras) }} to activity {com.example.proyecto/com.example.proyecto.Acceso_Camara}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-27 18:02:20.730: E/AndroidRuntime(11283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3557)
04-27 18:02:20.730: E/AndroidRuntime(11283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3600)
04-27 18:02:20.730: E/AndroidRuntime(11283):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:151
```

Comment: Plug your phone into your PC and monitor the Logcat data.

Comment: If im not wrong, for monitoring the Logcat data, Eclipse must recognize my phone's drivers... isnt it? Since I have a "white brand" mobile phone, Eclipse does not recognize my drivers and I cant monitor Logcat data.. 
Please, correct me if Im wrong and thank you for your quick answer

Comment: Go to your command shell, type "adb devices" with your phone plugged in. Does it show up? If not, download the USB drivers for your device.

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass the Bitmap objects to activities directly, on some devices this can cause out of memory exception. The better way to do this is to save the bitmap into a file and pass the file uri to the activity. Let the receiving activity read the bitmap from the file.
    Save the bitmap in your app's private directory so that it'll be deleted once app is uninstalled and also no other apps can access it.